# Whats wrong with my XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Im trying to get my XML styled into a table but Im having no luck at all.

At the moment Im trying to print the data into a table but its only printing the headings and not the data, what is going wrong here?

Heres what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdCQ1.jpg

My XML is well formed.
Something may be wrong with my XSL

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

<catalog>
<book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk103">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
  <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
  society in England, the young survivors lay the 
  foundation for a new society.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk104">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
  <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk105">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
  <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
  battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
  Oberon's Legacy.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk106">
  <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
  <title>Lover Birds</title>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
  <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
  conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk107">
  <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
  <title>Splish Splash</title>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
  <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
  thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk108">
  <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
  <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
  <genre>Horror</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
  <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
  centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk109">
  <author>Kress, Peter</author>
  <title>Paradox Lost</title>
  <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
  <price>6.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
  <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
  Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
  of being quantum.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk110">
  <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
  <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>36.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
  <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
  detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk111">
  <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
  <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>36.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
  <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
  detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
  SAX and more.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk212">
  <author>Galos, Mike</author>
  <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>49.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
  looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
  integrated into a comprehensive development 
  environment.</description>
 </book>
</catalog>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="catalog">

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Books Catalog by Author</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Books Catalog by Author</h1>

        <table border ="1" cellpadding ="5">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-by="author">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />

            <tr bgcolor="#ef9f37">

            <td colspan="4">
            Author:
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />

            </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>

    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Genre</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@id" />
    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
    <tr>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />    -->


        </table>
    </body>
    </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the COMPLETE stack trace (format as `code`).  How are you invoking Saxon? Since you tagged this `Java`, I assume you wrote some Java code that invokes XSL? Please include all the code having to do with invoking the XSL transform.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your script failed is that you closed `for-each-group` loop
**too early**. It actually prints only authors - "heads" of book groups.

The part of your template concerning the `table` tag should be constructed
as follows:

1. `for-each-group` (outer) loop, as you did.
2. *Author* and heading (2 rows), as you did.
3. Still **inside this outer loop**, place a `for-each` loop,
   looping over the content of the current group (books by particular author).
4. Its content should output a row (`<tr>` tag) and inside it 4 cells
   (`<td>` tags) with the proper content. The first of them contains `id`
   attribute of the current `book`, and the rest - values of selected
   children tags (*title*, *genre* and *price*).

So your template should look something like below:

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Books Catalog by Author</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Books Catalog by Author</h1>
      <table border ="1" cellpadding ="5">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-by="author">
          <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
          <tr bgcolor="#ef9f37">
            <td colspan="4">Author:
              <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>ID</td><td>Title</td><td>Genre</td><td>Price</td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="genre"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

By the way: Your concept to write `for-each-group` grouping books by `@id`
is strange. Notice that each book has **diffrent** *id*, so no group
would have contained more than 1 book.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't seem to be working, no data is being displayed only the heading, Author, ID,Title, Genre and Price.